# HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath findvalue returns concatenation of values

Tags: string, perl, xpath, concatenation, html-treebuilder

The `findvalue` function in [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm) returns a concatenation of any values found by the `xpath` query.

Why does it do this, and how could a concatenation of the values be useful to anyone?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it do this?

When you call `findvalue`, you're requesting a single scalar value. If there are multiple matches, they have to be combined into a single value *somehow*.

From the documentation for [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath#findvalue-path):

> **findvalue ($path)**
>
> ...If the path returns a NodeSet, `$nodeset->xpath_to_literal` is called automatically for you (and thus a Tree::XPathEngine::Literal is returned).

And from the documentation for [Tree::XPathEngine::NodeSet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tree::XPathEngine::NodeSet#xpath_to_literal):

> **xpath_to_literal()**
>
> Returns the concatenation of all the string-values of all the nodes in the list.

An alternative would be to return the Tree::XPathEngine::NodeSet object so the user could iterate through the results himself, but the `findvalues` method already returns a list.

---

> How could a concatenation of the values be useful to anyone?

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $content = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($content);

say $tree->findvalue('//p');

__DATA__
<p>HTML is just text.</p>
<p>It can still make sense without the markup.</p>
```

Output:

```
HTML is just text.It can still make sense without the markup.
```

Usually, though, it makes more sense to get a list of matches and iterate through them instead of doing dumb concatenation, so you should use `findvalues` (plural) if you could have multiple matches.

Comment: The more sensible behaviour would be for it to return the first match in a scalar context and all matches in a list context, which is what other modules do, eg. `look_down` in `HTML::Element`.

Comment: No. It shouldn't return something other than what you asked for. If you just want the first one, ask for just the first one

Comment: @ikegami So are you saying `look_down` in `HTML::Element`is wrong?

Comment: @ikegami So what is your opinion on `look_down` in `HTML::Element`?  It returns the first match in a scalar context and all matches in a list context.

Comment: @ikegami In the second comment to this answer you said it shouldn't do that.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not sure why you would want to defend what is quite an odd and unusable feature of the function.

Comment: @ikegami What I'm saying is that a concatenation is close to useless in most cases.

Comment: @ikegami In my opinion a function that concatenates all the values should be a separate function because it is an unusual requirement. There should simply be a `findvalues` function that returns the first match in a scalar context and all matches in a list context.

Comment: @ikegami  If it is "a totally redundant function" then why does `look_down` in `HTML::Element` do what I am asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
( $tree->findvalues('//p') )[0] ;
```

instead.